# Set an mapping for a simple parameter in a complex Json expectation

Tags: c#, json, .net, .net-core

I am facing a trouble due to a braking change I need to avoid for one API.

The thing is that I am expecting a parameter, lets call it `FilterParam<string> filter` which is a JSON parameter with properties `filterString` and `sorterString` .

My current problem is that I have some filters that are `string filter` and I need to convert them to `FilterParam<string> filter` but also support calls like the following `https://foo/fooget?filter=simpleString` right now, as this call has not the proper JsonFormat I am not being able to map this simple string just to the `filterString` property of the complex class.

The question is, if there a simple way or config (for deserializing) that allows me to set something like:

**If no format or no json, set param value to x property**

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you seem like trying to set property value. Please correct me if I misunderstand your question. Here is the code:

```
if (format == null || json == null) {
            filter.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p =>
            {
                // Find property name that are "filterString" and "sorterString"
                return p.Name == "filterString" || p.Name == "sorterString";
            }).ToList().ForEach(p =>
            {
                // Set value "X" to filterString and sorterString
                p.SetValue(filter, "X");
            });
}
```